# Encoding of input file for XSLT 2.0 function unparsed-text()

Tags: encoding, markdown, xslt-2.0, saxon, xpath-2.0

Let's say I have this `file.md` encoded in `UTF-8` (.md means it's markdown format)

```
Hello world
This text is encoded in UTF-8.
```

Then I approach it using function `unparsed-text('file.md', 'UTF-8')`. That works like a charm.

Problem shows up when (let's say) I use one of my native language (Czech) specific character, for example this `file2.md`:

```
Hello world
This character "š" is read like "sh" in english.
```

Using same encoding parameter in `unparsed-text()` I get error:

> XTDE1200: Failed to read input file file:/C:/file2.md
>   (java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException): Input length = 1

`file2.md` has same encoding UTF-8 as `file.md`, czech characters are in this charset, yet XSLT processor doesn't accept it. If I change encoding parameter to `windows-1250` ie. `unparsed-text('file2.md', 'windows-1250')` it works nicely.

So question is, why I get this error? Does it relate to the fact that input file is with extension .md (.txt works). Is there way around it? I really want to be able to use same encoding in my xsl stylesheet as supplied input file has.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: If `unparsed-text('file2.md', 'windows-1250')` works fine with that file and  `unparsed-text('file2.md', 'UTF-8')` does not work then the file is not UTF-8 encoded, it is encoded with that Windows code page. So how do you create that file, it sounds like your editor is not using UTF-8.

Comment: For ASCII characters like in the first file the encoding of UTF-8 is probably the same as with Windows-1250, that is why you don't get an error with such files that contain only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin says, the evidence you have provided suggests that the file is encoded in Windows-1252, and that `unparsed-text('file.md', 'utf-8')` is therefore right to reject it.

Comment: It appears that I misread the encoding of `file2.md` (simply I forgot to save file between changing of encoding). Martin explained cause of error perfectly. It twisted my head. Thanks you both!